# Sorting and paging issues with SQL Stored procedures and GridView

Tags: c#, sql-server, sorting, stored-procedures, gridview

I have been trying to find a good solution googling around and i am having little success on my current project to implement custom paging and Sorting on an ASp GridView Control (.NET 4.0).

This is the most current site i have attempted to use as a base to complete this task:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/GridViewCustomPaging.aspx

The biggest problem i have with this solution is that his example FirstID is an integer also his ProductID and I am using GUID's as my uniqueidentifier. This is obviously causing issues when I try to order by this or anything like that. I tried using another colum (AesExt varchar(50) ) but that is not working either, basically, it keeps saving the top row row for some reason. I also need to implement sorting, so when i get the procedure back in C#, I am stuffing it into a Datatable and using DataView to do the sorting. I was wondering if anyone out there had a better solution for this scenario they could share or show me what I am doing in correctly. I was also trying to find a good way to do the sorting in the procedure, but it won't work because my boss wanted extension as varchar(50) because there are none entries (personally i think it should be 0). So when I try to sort by AesExt, when i want to convert to int so the sort works right, it will blow up at none and i know looping in a procedure is a no no, so I'm stuck doing that in C# code I think.

Store procedure

```
USE [Inventory]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[usp_GetExtList]    Script Date: 06/26/2011 21:07:06 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description: <Description,,>
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_GetExtList]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@startRowIndex INT,
@maximumRows INT, 
@sortExpression AS VARCHAR(50),
@sortDirection AS VARCHAR(50),
@totalRows INT OUTPUT

AS

DECLARE @first_id INT
DECLARE @startRow INT

SET @startRowIndex =  ((@startRowIndex - 1)  * @maximumRows) +1

IF @startRowIndex = 1 
SET @startRowIndex = 1


SET ROWCOUNT @startRowIndex

SELECT @first_id = AesExt FROM ExtItem 

PRINT @first_id
SET ROWCOUNT @maximumRows

SELECT ExtensionGUID, AesExt,Name FROM ExtItem WHERE 
AesExt >= @first_id

/*ORDER BY CASE WHEN @sortExpression ='Name' AND @sortDirection = 'Ascending' THEN Name
                END ASC,
         CASE WHEN @sortExpression = 'Name' AND @sortDirection='Descending' THEN Name
                END DESC,
         CASE WHEN @sortExpression = 'AesExt' AND @sortDirection = 'Ascending' THEN AesExt
                END ASC,
         CASE WHEN @sortExpression = 'AesExt' AND @sortDirection='Descending' THEN AesExt
                END DESC,
         CASE WHEN @sortExpression = 'AgentExt' AND @sortDirection = 'Ascending' THEN AgentExt
                END ASC,
         CASE WHEN @sortExpression = 'AgentExt' AND @sortDirection='Descending' THEN AgentExt
                END DESC
 */

     SET ROWCOUNT 0
```

-- Get the total rows

```
SELECT @totalRows = COUNT(ExtensionGUID) FROM Extitem
```

C# Code

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            BindData();
    }

    #region BIND DATA

    private void BindData()
    {
        string connectionString = @"Server=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;" + "Database=Inventory;Trusted_Connection=true";

        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("usp_GetExtList", myConnection);

        myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startRowIndex", currentPageNumber);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@maximumRows", PAGE_SIZE);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sortExpression", SortExpression);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sortDirection", GridViewSortDirection);
        myCommand.Parameters.Add("@totalRows", SqlDbType.Int, 4);
        myCommand.Parameters["@totalRows"].Direction =
                           ParameterDirection.Output;

        SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(myCommand);

        //DataSet ds = new DataSet();
       // ad.Fill(ds);
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);

        DataView dataView = new DataView(dataTable);
        dataView.Sort = "AesExt ASC";
        gvProducts.DataSource = dataView;
        gvProducts.DataBind();

        // get the total rows 
        double totalRows = (int)myCommand.Parameters["@totalRows"].Value;

        lblTotalPages.Text = CalculateTotalPages(totalRows).ToString();

        lblCurrentPage.Text = currentPageNumber.ToString();

        if (currentPageNumber == 1)
        {
            Btn_Previous.Enabled = false;

            if (Int32.Parse(lblTotalPages.Text) > 0)
            {
                Btn_Next.Enabled = true;
            }
            else
                Btn_Next.Enabled = false;

        }

        else
        {
            Btn_Previous.Enabled = true;

            if (currentPageNumber == Int32.Parse(lblTotalPages.Text))
                Btn_Next.Enabled = false;
            else Btn_Next.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Ranhiru ... did you mean to post something? It does not show up here and I never got an email

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been abandoned and we are now using Select Top as the stored procedure. Word to the wise when using a GridView... it's all or nothing, so we are just going to use it to make it look nice and handle all the data handling